# Passing a map variable as a string to CodePipeline EnvironmentVariables section in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to pass a map variable per below :

```
variables "egress_ports" {
type = map(any)
default = {
"from_port" = 8443
"to_port" = 8443
}
description = "e-gress required by pipeline"
}
```

into Environment variable section of codepipeline in terraform per below

```
<stages>
{
EnvironmentVariables = jsonencode(var.egress_ports)
}
```

When i try like this.. getting the error that EnvironmentVariable section requires json array of strings.
Could someone please help how to pass it in.

Here is the Environment Variable section i am trying ::

```
EnvironmentVariables = templatefile("./pre-req.tmpl", {pipeline_name = var.pipeline_name, app_id = var.app_id, **egress_ports = jsonencode(var.egress_ports)** })
```

Everything works fine without egress_ports variable, as that is the only one which is map type. please help.

Thanks

Comment: You have to define one variable name per one line and assign it a value.

Comment: yeah i tried the same, there are more variables .. all are being taken fine but this one is facing issue , thats why only taken it into snippet above.

Comment: There is a lot of the context missing, so pretty hard to know what is it what you want to achieve.

Comment: attaching a pic of environmentvariable section, not able to type and paste here.. could you please help looking at this once..

Comment: in the pic.. if u see i am using template file and passing in variables there.. just when i append this line
egress_ports = jsonencode(var.egress_ports)
it starts failing.

Comment: Please do not add screenshots to questions, code blocks are more useful.

Comment: sorry to add screenshot, had done it in interest of time, will try to type the code here itself.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to transform your terraform variable input to follow this format and then pass it into EnvironmentVariables.

```
[
   {"name": "from_port", "value": "8443", "type": "PLAINTEXT"},
   {"name": "to_port", "value": "8443", "type": "PLAINTEXT"},
]
```